# Installing Adobe CC 2019 on Windows 10 LTSB 2016 without upgrading

Tags: windows, installation, upgrade, adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

i am a happy Windows LTSB 2016 user and I am not willing to upgrade it. However Adobe wants me to upgrade my OS in order to install their newest Adobe Products. Is there any Fix/Bypass to get around this Warning and keep my Windows?

Comment: LTSB is not intended for general computing use. It is designed by Microsoft for use only in very restrictive systems such as Kiosks and embedded controllers. Components of the OS Adobe may require are likely missing. Your only solution is to install the versions of Windows 10 intended for the function you wish to use your computer for.

Comment: What is Adobe suggesting you upgrade to?  Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB 2016 absolutely should be supported, it's Windows 10, so there is likely a missing detail that explains the behavior you describe.

Comment: From https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2553214 "...the latest versions of our applications require a newer build of Windows 10 as you have stated in your original post.  You can continue to use the Adobe Creative Cloud desktop application and older Adobe applications until your organization is prepared to upgrade Windows 10. "

Answer (score -1):

LTSB is not intended for general computing use. It is designed by Microsoft for use only in very restrictive systems such as Kiosks and embedded controllers. Components of the OS Adobe may require are likely missing. Your only solution is to install the versions of Windows 10 intended for the function you wish to use your computer for.

Don't believe me? Microsoft has been pretty consistent on the stated purpose for the LTSB/LTSC. The documentation can be found here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/ltsc/

And the important bits are as follows:

> The LTSC edition of Windows 10 provides customers with access to a
>   deployment option for their special-purpose devices and environments.
>   These devices typically perform a single important task and don’t need
>   feature updates as frequently as other devices in the organization.
>   These devices are also typically not heavily dependent on support from
>   external apps and tools.

More details can be found in this Microsoft article: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-IT-Pro-Blog/LTSC-What-is-it-and-when-should-it-be-used/ba-p/293181

Further, LTSB/LTSC may only be legally used by holders of a Windows 10 Enterprise license with a Volume License Agreement. This generally means that individuals do not have legal access to this license, and people who are legitimately using it are doing so as part of an enterprise and have dedicated IT staff who can and should be answering these sorts of questions for them.

Finally, it is a known issue, official by Adobe, that CC 2019 requires Windows 10 build 1703 minimum, and LTSB 2016 is Windows 10 build 1607:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2553214

> MichIGY, I am sorry, but the latest versions of our applications
>   require a newer build of Windows 10 as you have stated in your
>   original post.  You can continue to use the Adobe Creative Cloud
>   desktop application and older Adobe applications until your
>   organization is prepared to upgrade Windows 10.

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB isn't intended for general computing?  What?  Since when is a Long Term Support Branch of Windows 10 not mean to be used in general computing (commercial) environment?  Now, Adobe might no longer support Windows 10 LTSB 2016 for a variety of reasons, but the LTSB, was certainly designed to be used in a general computing office setting.

Comment: We've been over this before: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/ltsc/ The LTSC edition of Windows 10 provides customers with access to a deployment option for their special-purpose devices and environments. These devices typically perform a single important task and don’t need feature updates as frequently as other devices in the organization. These devices are also typically not heavily dependent on support from external apps and tools.

Comment: Further, LTSC is only an option for Enterprise licenses with a Volume License Agreement. Something very unlikely to be held by an individual, more likely to be managed by an enterprise with dedicated IT staff.

Comment: I can't remember what I had for lunch let alone remember what we have been over in the past.  While I understand individuals might not use Enterprise/Education/LTSB, I thought of nothing of the fact, Adobe CC 2019 was being installed on it.  Of course one would also think you simply use the last version of Adobe CC that does support 1607 in that case.

Comment: LOL. I'm starting to go through all my kids names before I get to the one whose face I'm staring at. I'm sorry for being snippy. People who still think LTSB/LTSC is the version they should be using on their desktop for normal use surprise me. If you're that upset about what Windows is right now, you should have bought an Apple, or gone Linux.